# Transition to default class upon removal of CSS class with animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

I am animating a button. A class is assigned depending on my app state. This is actually implemented in Svelte as follows:

```html
<div class="default"
     class:run-animation="{$animate === true}">
```

But the equivalent in vanilla javascript without Svelte is:

```html
let element = document... (find element)
element.classList.add("run-animation")
... later ...
element.classList.remove("run-animation)
```

For the sake of a minimum reproducible example, the classes I'm trying to animate/transition between look like this:

```css
.default {
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
}

@keyframes button-animation {
  from {
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
  }
  20% {
    top: 23px;
    color: white;
  }
  25% {
    color: red;
  }
  100% {
    top: 23px;
    color: red;
  }
}

.run-animation {
  animation-name: button-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  /* Preserve the effect of the animation at ending */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

I add the class to the element, and the button animates just like I want it to. My problem arises when I remove the class. I want the button to transition smoothly back to the default CSS. I have tried adding the animation to the run-animate class:

```css
.run-animation {
  animation-name: ... ;
  
  top: 23px;
  color: red;
}
```

I have come across many people stating the transition upon class removal will apply if I add a transition property to the default class. I have tried this as follows:

```css
.default {
  ...
  transition: all 3s linear;
}
```

But it isn't working. The animation runs smoothly when it is added but the styling immediately reverts to the default when the class is removed (no smooth transition).

**MY GOAL: I want to smoothly transition away from the end-state of the animation to the default class when the animate class is removed. Is this possible?**

Ideally, I'm adding the class with the Svelte logic at the top so the animation should not be triggered in javascript but rather naturally occur as a result of class assignment.

(My code in practice is a little more complicated than shown, the button has another class with styles not being animated at all and the animation includes more styles such as box-shadow and text-shadow. Still, I don't see why this should be more problematic than just color and top included above)

```js
// JS only toggles '.animation'
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("div.default").classList.toggle("animation");
});
```

```css
body {display: flex}
button {position: absolute; left: 120px}
div.default {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: darkgreen;
}
/* Above code to make a visible working example */

div.default {
  top: 20px;
  color: white;
  transition: top 0.4s, color 0.1s 0.4s;
}

@keyframes define-animation {
  from {
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
  }
}

div.default.animation {
  animation-name: define-animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  
  top: 24px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="default">I'm colourful</div>
<button>Toggle ".animation"-class</button>
```

Above is a working snippet with an animation running on class addition and no reverse transition on class removal. I have tried setting animation direction to opposite values in .default and .animation. I have tried defining the .animate end state properties in the class and/or in the keyframes to attributes.

EDIT: It works now! How?
You cannot apply:
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
The end-attributes need to be defined in the animate class not in the keyframe.

The animation plays when the class is added. Transition timings are used when the class is removed (if the animation has completed).

Comment: You should try to add a working Stack-snippet in your question, containing all necessary code. With several snippets -only containing parts of your code- it is hard to follow. Now since you want to show two examples both with and without using Svelte, it would be good to have [self-contained examples](http://sscce.org/) in your question for every instance you named.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a transition effect, you can use the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)-property.
The `transition`-property can be used here, since every property you want to animate only has a start- and end-value.

**Translating animation-percentages to seconds**
To translate the percentages of your [CSS Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) `button-animation` to seconds, you just calculate `'percentage' * 'animation-duration'`.
This works for both the `transition-duration`-property as well as for the `transition-delay`-property.

Example:
`color` is being animated from 20% to 25%, which is a duration of 5% with a delay of 20%.
All in all, the animation should take 2 seconds.
So we calculate for:

- `transition-duration`: `5% * 2s = 0.1s`
- `transition-delay`: `20% * 2s = 0.4s`

With that, we can add `transition: color 0.1s 0.4s` to the `.default`-class.

**Why add it to `.default`, and not to `.animation`?**
If we were to add the `transition`-property to `.animation`, the following would happen:

- When adding `.animation`, there will be a transition-effect, since the element now has a `transition`-property defined.
- But when removing `.animation`, the element would *no longer* have a `transition`-property defined, meaning there would be no transition.

Now, we want to transition on both adding and removing `.animation`, meaning we want to have a `transition`-property defined both when `.animation` is present and when it is not. That means, `transition` should not be defined in `.animation`.

```js
// JS only toggles '.animation'
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("div.default").classList.toggle("animation");
});
```

```css
body {display: flex}
button {align-self: center}
div.default {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: darkgreen;
}
/* Above code to make a visible working example */

div.default {
  top: 20px;
  color: white;
  transition: top 0.4s, color 0.1s 0.4s;
}
div.default.animation {
  top: 23px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="default">Some text to see the "color"-property</div>
<button>Toggle ".animation"-class</button>
```

**Why does it behave differently...**
...when placing the properties inside the `to`-section of the animation, than when placing them inside `.animation` itself?

That is, because the properties are not directly applied to the element itself, but rather the element is stopped in its animation (right at the very end), giving only the *appearance* of the properties being actually applied.
Removing `animation-fill-mode: forwards` shows the actually applied properties *after* the animation has played. Those actually applied properties will be the start-values for `transition` after `.animation` is removed.

When defining these properties in `.animation`, they will inherently be the `to`-values for the animation (if not defined otherwise in animation itself), *and* be the applied properties of the element.
That means, when removing `.animation`, the transition will start from there.

Comment: Ok! This is awesome.

I played around with your code a little and it seems I can have separate timings for the animation being applied:
` div.default.animation {
transition
}`
 and removed: 
` div.default {
transition in
}`
I'm guessing the .animation transition property is read in before the animation begins and overwrites the default. Like you say, it shouldn't exist when the class is removed.
Is my thinking right?

Comment: Another point, I think your solution will work for what I'm building now.

I'm lucky my animation consists of delayed smooth transitions between only two values. If I wanted to animate one way i.e. interpolate more values or define complex movements, is it then be possible to transition back to default upon class removal?

Comment: When properties are defined in a [more specific selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), then those rules override previous defined ones. So when `transition` is differently defined in `.animation` than in `.default`, then when that class is applied, those rules apply as well.

Comment: For more complex behaviour than just a direct transition between values, you should use CSS Animations, that is correct. And to reverse the animation, you can use `animation-direction: reverse`. With what I said in my previous comment, you can set the direction to `normal` in `.animation`, and reverse it in `.default` to always animate back to the original values.

Comment: Tbh, I'm not sure. You had `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to let the element stay in the state at the end of the animation, which would (I think!) override any other property defined in both `.default` and `.animation`. With this, the element only has these set properties because it is stopped in that state, however, it does not actually have them applied. That means, those would not be the beginning values of an animation when removing `.animation`. Will sit down now to test this, and report back.

Comment: I added a small stack-snippet with exactly the scenario I am working from. The animation runs on apply and the transition does not on removal. Am excited to hear how your tests go!

Comment: Updated the answer with a somewhat better explanation of what I tried to explain in my last comment.